# show the list of files from google drive folder in a modal dialog

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm trying to get a list of files in one of my drive folder to be displayed using .showModalDialog
here is what i've got so far

///gs.code

```
function ImportSBMessage() {
        var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Message');
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
       .showModalDialog(html, 'List of files in folder');
}

function getfiles(){

    var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('attach to Email').next().getId();
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFiles();
   while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file);
    return file
  }
```

}

///html........(this part i don't know how to do it so it will return my list of files)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

</head>
 <body>
   <script>

   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getfile();


   </script>






  </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the file list under a folder.
- You want to show the file list to the dialog.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

#### For Google Apps Script side

- `var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('attach to Email').next().getId();` and `var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFiles();` can be modified to `var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('attach to Email').next().getFiles();`.

#### For HTML side

- When `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getfile()` is run, there is no function of `getfile()` at Google Apps Script side. At Google Apps Script side, the function name is `getfiles()`.
- In your case, you can use the list retrieved from `getfiles()` of Google Apps Script side at `withSuccessHandler()`.

  - At `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getfile()`, after `getfile()` was finished, `function` of `withSuccessHandler(function)` is run. At that time, the values from `getfile()` can be used as the arguments.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `getfiles()` as follows.

```
function getfiles(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('attach to Email').next().getFiles();  // Modified
  var fileList = [];  // Added
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileList.push({filename: file.getName(), fileId: file.getId()});  // Added
  }
  return fileList;  // Modified
}
```

- In this modification, the filenames and file IDs of files are returned as an array.

#### HTML side:

Please modify the body tag as follows. From your HTML, I could confirm that you are using jquery. So this modification also uses it.

```
<body>
  <ul></ul> <!-- Added -->
  <script>
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(list => {  // Modified
    const li = list.reduce((s, e) => s += "<li>" + e.filename + "(" + e.fileId + ")</li>", "");
    $("ul").append(li);
  }).getfiles();
  </script>
</body>
```

- In this modification, the list is appended using the retrieved array.

### Note:

- In above modified script, when `ImportSBMessage()` is run at the script editor, a dialog is opened, and `getfiles()` is run. Then, the file list is shown.
- This is a simple sample script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)
- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks again Tanaike that is  what i needed i was trying to accomplish how would i modify the line fileList.push({filename: file.getName(), fileId: file.getId()}); to only return the file name without the ID field

Comment: I got it to only show the file names by modifying the html script line const li = list.reduce((s, e) => s += "<li>" + e.filename + "(" + e.fileId + ")</li>", "");
    $("ul").append(li); to const li = list.reduce((s, e) => s += "<li>" + e.filename + "</li>", "");
    $("ul").append(li); not the best way for sure but now it shows only the file name thanks

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that your modification is good.